# What android store my app has been downloaded from?

Tags: android

I don't need to know the information for myself, but to detect the information within the app to provide links to other apps depending on the store it was downloaded from.

Is it possible and how?

Comment: What do you mean by "what android store". I think users can download trusted and authorized apps from Google play only. Other links to download app are not authorized.

Comment: Provide these stores with different app versions.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal - Amazon Kindle devices have their own Android store separate from Google Play. I'm sure there are many other examples of a telco carrier or device vendors that do not enable Google Play.

Comment: @selbie ohh... yes got it.. thanks for the information.. but according to me if a user has to upload app to differnt stores individually so he can easily detect the store app was downloaded from using different variables for each file,then he can set information locally on device or on server.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav! But the question is not having to compile for different stores. I have my apps in more than six stores, and I need to compile three different versions each time I want to update them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `market://details?id=<package_name>`

From an Android app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

[Linking from an Android App](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app) this will launch android market or any other play store present on device. Tested with onemobile and playstore on a device, not sure if it will work with all other play stores.

Another approach can be uploading different versions on different stores
Or Open link in browser.

Comment: Hi Sunny! I will try it, but I think it won't work ,as market://det...  is a standard for Google play. For example, Amazon for its store has this one: amzn://apps/android...  And here the question is to know which one I have to use before using the link. The approach I am currently using is the second one, compiling different versions for the different stores.